# Converting pt and px

Tags: css

I'm trying to understand converting PT to PX. I'm using Photoshop, HTML and CSS and it doesn't seem to work out the same in the browser. I understand that you can work it out by using this: points = pixels * 72 / 96? Is 96 the DPI set on the computer? Will the resolution of the screen or the resolution you set in Photoshop effect the formula as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the [CSS Values and Units Level 3](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#absolute-lengths) specification, the physically sized units (including `pt`) are defined to be their physical size on the given medium (so `1cm` is the same size on screen and paper). The `px` (pixel) unit is defined in terms of a reference pixel of `96dpi` irrespective of the resolution of the medium being displayed.

Older versions of the CSS specification did not define a pixel to be `96dpi`, but most of the existing content depends on this assumption so using another DPI value would break existing content.

You have `1px = 1/96in => 96px = 1in` due to the definition of the reference pixel.

You have `1pt = 1/72in => 72pt = 1in` due to the definition of the point.

Therefore, combining the two equations, you have:

```
   72pt = 96px
=> (72 / 96)pt = 1px
```

multiplying both sides of the equation by `P` (the number of pixels) gives you:

```
P(72 / 96)pt = Ppx
```

which is the equation you have.

You need to make sure that the DPI settings for Photoshop are set to the equivalent settings.

Comment: Really old question but worth a correction I think. The formula is px =  pt / 72 * 96 or px = (96 / 72)pt. You have the inverse in your answer. To check, 9pt = 12px approx. 
Simply stated:  px = pt*1.33333333.